# dbt source definition with dbt_utils get_relations_by_pattern and union_relations

Tags: dbt

I am creating unioned models of multiple tables that are split by year in our source (ex. TABLENAME2020, TABLENAME2021, etc) with the following code:

```
{% set relations = dbt_utils.get_relations_by_pattern(
    database='DBNAME',
    schema_pattern='SCHEMA',
    table_pattern='TABLENAME%') %}

with source as (
    select * from (
        {{ dbt_utils.union_relations(relations=relations) }}
    )
)

select * from source
```

This functions fine, however, I am wondering if there is a way to define the source in my `sources.yml` file that would correctly represent this in the dbt generated documentation?

Comment: In effect you are looking to define a source which references something like a [wildcard table](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/querying-wildcard-tables) for the backend? And what warehouse  / server are you using?